# Extjs Grid with pagination not loading on loadData

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to load data in the extjs grid with paging toolbar using loaddata but it shows empty grid.
The data returned is

```
       {

        "data": [{
            "id": "user1",
            "title": "index0"
        }, {
            "id": "user2",
            "title": "index1"
        }, {
            "id": "user3",
            "title": "index2"
        }, {
            "id": "user4",
            "title": "index3"
        }],
    "total": 8,
    }
```

My code looks like

```
initcomponent:function(){
    defaultModel:[{
                            header: 'Date',
                            dataIndex: 'id',
                            sortable: true                        
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'title',
                            dataIndex: 'title',
                            sortable: false,

                        }];

    }     
    this.currStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

            fields : ['id','title'],


            pageSize:4,
            autoLoad:false,
            proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'data',
                        totalProperty:'total',
                    }
                }
        });

        this.currStore.load({
            params:{
                start:0,
                limit: 4,
            }
    }); 

    var config =
    {
        columns     : this.defaultModel,
        store       : this.currStore,
        columnLines : true,
        loadMask    : true,
        autoScroll  : true,
        tbar : [{
            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'Refresh',
            iconCls : 'btn-refresh',
            scope : this,
            handler : this.refreshGridData
        }],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: this.currStore,   // same store GridPanel is using
            dock: 'bottom',
            id:'pagingErrNot1',
            pageSize:4,
            displayInfo: true,
            emptyMsg: "No notification  to display",
            listeners:{
                beforechange : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : function(pagingtoolbar,pageNumber,scope)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }],
    };

    Ext.apply(this,config);
    this.callParent(arguments);
    }
```

data is of the form given above and setdata is called after the data is returned from server side.

```
    setData:function(data)
    {
        this.getStore().loadData(data);
        this.getView().refresh();

    }
```

but after loadData, grid is empty and and pagingtoolbar shows disabled.WHat am i doing wrong?

Comment: It probably throws an error. Please, open the chrome console to see it and attach the error to your post. Edit: Try this: `this.getStore().loadData(data.data);`

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. and yes if I load with 'data.data' but then how do we set 'totalProperty'.of grid

Comment: That is why you must use a remote proxy, instead of memory. You cant use pagination with memory proxy that way. Why dont you use ajax or jsonp proxy so that store can handle everythin internally ?

Comment: if your data is static or testing, you should insert data code in store.

Comment: You can also use `this.getStore().setData(data)`